# How do add python libraries to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-api

I just made my first function that fetches data from an excel sheet in Google Sheets. I got an error:

`"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'googleapiclient'"`

so i googled how to upload python modules (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBt8MXHcaPI) and it said to create a virtual env in something like VSCode, pip install the libraries that i'll need, then zip them and add them as a layer to Lambda.

I did that, twice. (It just looked like a whole bunch of libraries were being installed, so i looked up how to remove all of them (`pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y`) and tried again). So here's the starting point and after doing `pip install google-api-python-client`
[image]
[image]
[image]

I guess i'm a little confused whether i should be zipping up literally all of that, or just the stuff that has `google` in the name. I tried it both ways and neither seemed to work. I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Recommend you start with a simple Python script that simply imports a single third-party dependency e.g. requests and follow the AWS [packaging documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency). And understand the [quota limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution).

Answer (score 2):

You can include the third-party libraries [directly in your Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) .zip deployment. There is no need to create a Lambda layer for those. I suggest trying that first, as creating layers can be a bit more complicated. With everything in a single .zip file you can open the zip file and verify the libraries are in the correct location relative to your Python script.

> I guess i'm a little confused whether i should be zipping up literally all of that, or just the stuff that has google in the name. I tried it both ways and neither seemed to work.

You should be zipping up everything in there. If pip downloaded all those other libraries because the Google library you are using depends on them, then they all need to be part of your Lambda function as well.

Comment: i made the zip file, but getting an error `Unable to locate credentials.` when trying to run a`ws lambda update-function-code --function-name test_function --zip-file fileb://my-deployment-package.zip --region us-west-2` .

i ran gimme-aws-creds thinking that might fix it, but no :<

Comment: This is just a problem with your local AWS credentials configuration. I don't know what `gimme-aws-creds` is, but how were you deploying the Lambda before? Is this your first time using the AWS CLI tool? You should be setting credentials in `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables, or setting them in your `~/.aws/credentials` file and specifying the profile in `AWS_PROFILE` or via `--profile`.

Comment: i haven't deployed to Lambda before, i'm literally learning it just now :) gimme-aws-creds is what generates the ~/.aws/credentials file ... so i guess it's not seeing it for some reason. Maybe i need to have the function be in the same folder or something?

Comment: If you never deployed the Lambda before, how were you getting the error messages you included in your question? And **no absolutely do not** place the credentials file anywhere other than the `~/.aws/credentials` folder.

Comment: well, i mean i did try deploying it earlier when i wrote the code right in the aws Code source window. That's when i starting messing with trying to upload the python libraries with layers. But someone else said that I should just have the libraries directly in the main package, which is what i'm guessing this process of updating the function with the zip containing all the things is.

Comment: If you are having trouble obtaining AWS credentials and configuring them for the AWS CLI tool that is worth posting a separate question on this site, and then maybe someone familiar with the `gimme-aws-creds` tool will be able to provide you a full answer to that question. Alternatively you can just upload the .zip file through the AWS web console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-zip.html#configuration-function-update

Comment: i just copy pasted the credential from credentials file into aws configure and tried running it again.... it thought for a while, then came back with `SSL validation failed for https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/test_function/code EOF occurred in violation of protocol`

Comment: Now it sounds like you don't have network access or something. Why don't you try uploading it through your browser?

Comment: i was hoping that was an option! But not sure where. Just to S3?

Comment: I posted a link to the documentation a few comments up.

Comment: uploaded the zip to S3 but now it's saying `Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes` urghhhhhhh ....

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you look at [**AWS SAM**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)

AWS SAM is an extension of CloudFormation that simplifies the development of serverless applications.

To deploy a AWS Lambda function using AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM), you need to follow these steps:

- Create a SAM template: This is a YAML file that defines the AWS resources you want to deploy, including the Lambda function and its dependencies.
- Package the function: Package the function code and any dependencies into a .zip file. (For this you'll need a requirements.txt file with all the dependencies your code needs)
- Deploy the function: Use the AWS CLI command deploy to deploy the SAM template and function code to AWS. The command will create or update a CloudFormation stack, which creates or updates the specified AWS resources.

Example SAM template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: main.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: .
      Description: "This is my SAM function"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
```

Example AWS CLI command:

```
sam build --debug --template-file template.yaml
sam package --s3-bucket your_s3_bucket --s3-prefix sam-deployments \
                  --output-template-file packaged-template.yaml
sam deploy -t packaged-template.yaml --stack-name your_stack_name \
          --region your_aws_region --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

A common folder structure for a Lambda project using AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) would look something like this:

```
my-lambda-project/
├── main.py # Lambda function code
├── template.yaml # SAM template
├── requirements.txt # Python dependencies
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. How does one create a yaml file?

Comment: You can use an IDE like VSCode, Atom or Notepad++ to create a new .yaml file and use the example in the answer to start creating your own template. In this [YAML guide](https://circleci.com/blog/what-is-yaml-a-beginner-s-guide/#:~:text=YAML%20is%20a%20digestible%20data,that%20JSON%20can%20and%20more.) you can learn more about this format

Comment: is it in the settings somewhere? i can't seem to find it. I guess I'm not sure sure what i'm looking for either tho :< Does it get automatically generated from the python code somehow?

Comment: To create a YAML file using Visual Studio Code:
Click on the "File" menu and select "New File";
In the new file, enter the desired YAML code;
Click on the "File" menu and select "Save As";
In the "Save As" dialog, choose a destination for the file and enter a name including the ".yaml" extension;
Click "Save".

Comment: oh, i guess i don't really know what a yaml file is then or what's suppose to go in it %\

Answer (score 0):

I am using two ways of installing a Python module.

**1 Use AWS Lambda layers**
[image]

Resources:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXjMrWCpaI8

**2 Use Docker images**

- Create a Docker image and upload it to Amazon ECR
- Create your Lambda function using a container (Docker image)

Resources:

- How to create a Lambda container image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html
- How to create a Lambda function using a container image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-lambda-functions-with-container-images.html

Answer (score 0):

To use any 3rd party library in lambda you can use a lambda layer.

install the dependency using following command

`pip3 install <your_package> -t .`

zip the package

`zip -r your_pkg_layer.zip .`

create the layer in `aws` and upload the zip, after that add the `layer` to your `lambda` function

you can follow [this](https://medium.com/brlink/how-to-create-a-python-layer-in-aws-lambda-287235215b79) blog in medium.

Comment: You don't have to use a Lambda layer, you can include them directly in the .zip deployment of the Lambda function itself. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html That was the only way to include third-party libraries when Lambda first came out, before they added the Layers feature. If you aren't reusing those dependencies across multiple Lambda functions it can also be a lot simpler to just bundle them in the function's deployment.

Comment: yes I agree on that but with lambda bundle  I have faced several issues while importing the package itself in lambda. And personally I find the layer option simpler than bundling the dependencies together.